# Reference for age-period-cohort models

Tags: references

I work in the loss forecasting area and would like to know a little bit more about the theory and implementation of age-period-cohort models. Several papers pop up in google search but I need a more comprehensive material relating to identification/estimation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

Carstensen, B. (2007). "Age-period-cohort models for the Lexis diagram." Stat Med 26(15): 3018-3045.

> Analysis of rates from disease
>   registers are often reported
>   inadequately because of too coarse
>   tabulation of data and because of
>   confusion about the mechanics of the
>   age-period-cohort model used for
>   analysis. Rates should be considered
>   as observations in a Lexis diagram,
>   and tabulation a necessary reduction
>   of data, which should be as small as
>   possible, and age, period and cohort
>   should be treated as continuous
>   variables. Reporting should include
>   the absolute level of the rates as
>   part of the age-effects. This paper
>   gives a guide to analysis of rates
>   from a Lexis diagram by the
>   age-period-cohort model. Three aspects
>   are considered separately: (1)
>   tabulation of cases and person-years;
>   (2) modelling of age, period and
>   cohort effects; and (3)
>   parametrization and reporting of the
>   estimated effects. It is argued that
>   most of the confusion in the
>   literature comes from failure to make
>   a clear distinction between these
>   three aspects. A set of
>   recommendations for the practitioner
>   is given and a package for R that
>   implements the recommendations is
>   introduced.

//M